# get a html element from another website (XSS)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How can I get a html element from another website directly into my site (not using an iframe).

For Example:

A page on another website has the following code (and nothing else);

```
<p>example text</p>
```

how can I get this into my website to be able to edit it. I can't directly copy the code because I want the code on my site to change in conjunction to the other site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you seem to have PHP tag, so if using PHP, you can use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), like

```
$html = file_get_contents('url_of_site/page.html');
```

or with [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), like:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://some_site.com/');    

$html = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p');
print_r($html);
```

Note:: Due to [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), you cant do it with just javascript. If you want to do it with Javascript you need to create a proxy kinda stuff, like have a `test.php` file in your own server, add code to fetch content from other site into `test.php` file, and call this `test.php` file using javascript ajax.

Comment: It's worth noting that without PHP, this isn't possible (implied by your first sentence, but I wanted to make it clearer to @WebDev80)

Comment: Thank you, the first one does exactly want I wanted.

Comment: Using the PHP method, how do I select a specific element on the external website? For example; `file_get_contents('https://google.com/, #search-bar')`.